# What benefit does Django-Taggit provide over a simple ManyToManyField() implementation of tagging?

Tags: django, tags, tagging

The API according to the documentation seems achievable with a simple ManyToManyField...what am I missing?

Sample from Django-Taggit documentation:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    # ... fields here

    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Then you can use the API like so::

```
>>> apple = Food.objects.create(name="apple")
>>> apple.tags.add("red", "green", "delicious")
>>> apple.tags.all()
[<Tag: red>, <Tag: green>, <Tag: delicious>]
>>> apple.tags.remove("green")
>>> apple.tags.all()
[<Tag: red>, <Tag: delicious>]
>>> Food.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["red"])
[<Food: apple>, <Food: cherry>]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real advantage is not in finding the tags of an object, but rather the objects for a tag.  And specifically, if you have multiple types of objects that can be tagged, imagine:

```
class Food(models.Model):
   tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Wine(models.Model):
   tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Now find me all the instances of objects tagged "purple".  Taggit makes it a lot easier to do so.

Comment: So in your example, the only way to get all the tagged instances would be Tag.food_set.all(), Tag.wine_set.all()? If I'm pretty sure that different types won't need to be tagged, then a ManyToManyField should be ok right?