# Using django-taggit, is it possible to limit the tags to pre approved values?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a question about the use of django-taggit.  I have a UserProfile (which I attach using AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in the settings file) in which I store a set of skills for tutors such as: , , etc.  Then, when someone wants to request a tutoring session, they can write a description of what they want and place tags for their request.  (For example, I want a tutor skilled in calculus and physics).  If I let the users of the site choose their own tags, then I worry that we could end up with "tag hell" where we have tags such as , , etc.  So, I want to tag skills, but only from a table that I populate in the admin as we add people.  That avoids the diffusion problem (similar to how stackoverflow works).

Here is some trial Code:

```
from django.db import models </br>
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class BaseUser(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skills=TaggableManager()

class UserProfile(BaseUser):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,unique=True)

class TutoringSession(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique=True,blank=False,editable=False)
    tags=TaggableManager()
```

Or, is it better to use a Tags class:

```
class Tags:
     name=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)
```

and set up a ManyToMany relation to it in both TutoringSession and UserProfile?

Thanks!

I should note that this is related to question:
[What benefit does Django-Taggit provide over a simple ManyToManyField() implementation of tagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180251/what-benefit-does-django-taggit-provide-over-a-simple-manytomanyfield-implement)

except that in that example, we might want to limit the set of allowed answers to red and purple (that we've defined in a table because it might change)

Answer (score 1):

So you want a set of predefined tags and the Users as well as the TutoringSessions should relate to one or more of these tags. Thats (as far as I can see) what m2m-fields are made for.
Maybe taggit has some usability advantages (I'm not familiar with it), but the functionality described here can be achieved with simple m2m-fields.